# How to Fix display Size of Date?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, date

[image: My photo]

```html
<div class="input-group col-sm-3">
  <input id="date1" onkeypress="return isDateKey(event,this)" name="date1" class="form-control" data-toggle="datepicker-icon" date-picker>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="input-group-prepend datepicker-trigger" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <div class="input-group-text" id="btnDt_Rec">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

When I drag to Tablet or phone size the datepicker become bigger.

And what i want is normal size like picture below:

[image: Normal Size]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the choosing of your bootstrap column size. `col-sm-*` will resize everything wider than 576 pixels. I guess your tablet does not fall in that category. Try using `col-*` for anything smaller. If that doesn't work you might want to use flex.

Here's the documentation on the latter: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/